# How to setup a serialized (non-concurrent) InvokeMethodJob using Quartz 2.x plugin in Grails 2

Tags: quartz-scheduler, grails-2.0

Quartz 2 documentation is clear for setting up SimpleJobDetail so that it executes serialized (i.e. the next job runs *after* the the current job completes) by setting concurrent = false. Quartz 2 documentation is also clear for how to setup a job to invoke a spring bean method using InvokeMethodJob. But what is not clear is how to setup InvokeMethodJob to only run serialized (concurrent=false). I setup InvokeMethodJob like this in conf/Config.groovy:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.*
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*
import org.quartz.impl.triggers.*
import org.quartz.JobDataMap
import org.quartz.JobDetail
import org.quartz.Trigger
import grails.plugin.quartz2.InvokeMethodJob
//Begin quartz configuration
grails.plugin.quartz2.autoStartup = true
    org{
        quartz{
            scheduler.instanceName = 'MyScheduler'
    threadPool.class = 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool'
    threadPool.threadCount = 20
    threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
            jobStore.class = 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore'
        }
    }
grails.plugin.quartz2.jobSetup.mySchedule = { quartzScheduler, ctx  ->
    def props = new JobDataMap([concurrent:false,targetObject:ctx.myActionService,targetMethod:'myaction',arguments:[true]])
    JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(InvokeMethodJob.class)
        .withIdentity("perform my action")
        .usingJobData(props)
        .build()
    Trigger trigger = newTrigger().withIdentity("every 90 seconds trigger")
        .withSchedule(
            simpleSchedule().withIntervalInSeconds(90).repeatForever()
        )
        .startNow().build()
    quartzScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger)
}
```

However this will allow several threads to execute the myActionService.myaction() call concurrently. I would like the scheduler to stop further calls to this until the first call returns.

I read about @DisallowConcurrentExecution but there is not a way to apply that (or an example of how to apply that) in a definition within conf/Config.groovy.

Best solution I could devise was to create a new Groovy Class extend InvokeMethodJob and annotate with @DisallowConcurrentExecution like this:

```
package com.fourgablesguy.quartz2

import grails.plugin.quartz2.InvokeMethodJob
import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution

/**
 * InvokeMethodJob that is not concurrently executed, serial execution
 * this has the DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation
 */
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
class SerializedInvokeMethodJob extends InvokeMethodJob { }
```

Then change conf/Config.groovy to use this new Job class type:

```
import com.fourgablesguy.quartz2.SerializedInvokeMethodJob
...
JobDetail jobDetail = newJob(SerializedInvokeMethodJob.class)
```

But I may have missed something less complex that could be done instead to accomplish the same using quartz 2, so I posted this if anyone has a different solution.

Comment: you have given threadCount = 20 means there would be no of concurrent threads working on it. May be you can just replaced it with 1.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution I have found is described in the question, annotate a custom InvokeMethodJob class with @DisallowConcurrentExecution

The threadCount = 1 might be an option if your system only ever does one task. If you have several different jobs, you would need a higher thread count so they could run in parallel (some jobs you might want be non-concurrent.) Once the thread count is higher than 1, you are not guaranteed a non-concurrent execution for any job.